# Issue compiling variables in alternate method to output desired statements?

Tags: java

I've written this program and am having issues with my method call to "calculateTotalPrice". I have a logic error somewhere that is not compiling my code to the proper output format (Giving final price, items ordered, taxes associated with the purchase and a total price). It would be greatly appreciated if someone could try and tweak my code to allow the program to compile properly, thank you.

```
public class GrapefruitOrderingArray {

//Declare Constants 
public static final int SIZE = 100;
public static final int[] itemPrices = {49,299,329,399,199,1299,1199,999,599};  //Declare integer variable array itemPrices


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
 // Declare Variables
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);                                    
    String CustomerName;                                                        
    int[] naNumber = new int [SIZE];                                            
    int nProducts = 0;                                                          
    double nTotal = 0;                                                          
    double dFinalPrice = 0.0;                                                   
    int nCount = 0;                                                             


    //Declare Constants 
    final int SENTINEL = 10; 
    final double SALES_TAX = 0.065;

    //Prompt user to enter name
    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");

    //Enter user name
    CustomerName = input.nextLine();

    //Print Blank Line 
    System.out.println("");

    //Begin Product Listing Declarations with respect to array above
    System.out.println("GRAPEFRUIT PRODUCT:");

    System.out.println("1. gPod shuffle $" + itemPrices[0]);

    System.out.println("2. gPod Touch   $" + itemPrices[1]);

    System.out.println("3. gPad Mini    $" + itemPrices[2]);

    System.out.println("4. gPad 2       $" + itemPrices[3]);

    System.out.println("5. gPhone       $" + itemPrices[4]);

    System.out.println("6. gMac         $" + itemPrices[5]);

    System.out.println("7. MacNovel Pro $" + itemPrices[6]);

    System.out.println("8. MacNovel Air $" + itemPrices[7]);

    System.out.println("9. MiniMac      $" + itemPrices[8]);

    System.out.println("10. Complete my order");

    //Keep reading until the input is 100
    System.out.println("\nPlease select an item from the menu above: ");

    //Read number entered by the user
    naNumber[nCount] = input.nextInt();



     //Begin while-loop statement
    if (naNumber[nCount] != SENTINEL)   
 {
    //If desired the user may select another or multiple products now    
    System.out.println("\nPlease select another item from the menu above: ");

    //Read number entered by the user
    naNumber[nCount] = input.nextInt();

    nCount++;
 }

    System.out.println("Thank you for ordering with Grapefruit Company, " + CustomerName);



        //Call final price calculation
        dFinalPrice = calculateTotalPrice(naNumber,itemPrices,nTotal);


            //Print blank line to screen
            System.out.println("");

            //Total amount of product ordered
            System.out.println("Total items ordered: " + nProducts );

            //Total price of items ordered
            System.out.println("Price of items ordered: $" + nTotal );

            //Sales tax associated with the purchase
            System.out.println("Sales tax: $" + SALES_TAX * nTotal);

            //Total amount due by the customer to Grapefruit Co. 
            System.out.println("Total amount due: $" + (SALES_TAX * nTotal + nTotal));
    } //End main method

/**
 * This method calculates the total price of the products ordered
 * @param naNumber      Individualized product prices
 * @param itemPrices          Total price of items paid for
 * @return nTotal       Returns the number of the product associated with it's initialized  price
 */
  private static double calculateTotalPrice(int[] naNumber, int[] itemPrices, double nTotal) {

    int nCount = 0;
    int nProducts = 0;

    //Calculate entered items
    for(int i = 0; i < naNumber.length; i++){
      if(naNumber[i] != 0) {
      double itemTotal = itemPrices[i] * naNumber[i];
      nTotal += itemTotal;
      }
    }

    return nTotal;




  } //end method calculateTotalPriceOfItemsOrdered 
} //end class calculateTotalPriceOfItemsOrdered
```

Comment: What's the input, expected output and actual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the problem is here:

```
nTotal = nTotal + itemPrices[naNumber[nCount]-1];
```

This will not calculate the total price for every item.

Assuming that `int[] naNumber` is an array of the amount of times you bought an item and `int[] itemPrices` are the respective prices, you should change it to the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < naNumber.length; i++){
 if(naNumber[i] != 0) {
  double itemTotal = itemPrices[i] * naNumber[i];
  nTotal += itemTotal;
 }
}
```

Some other remarks:

- Your comments are either wrong or not needed. Examples:

> /**
>    * @param args the command line arguments
>    */

Thats obvious, it's the only possible argument. You have to describe that they represent, not what they are.

> //Read number entered by the user

What number?

> //Begin while-loop statement

There's no `while` loop.

And so on.

- `private static double calculateTotalPrice(int[] naNumber, int[] itemPrices, double nTotal)`

You don't have to pass in `double nTotal`, it serves no purpose.

To fix the output:

```
        //Total amount of product ordered
        System.out.println("Total items ordered: " + nCount);

        //Total price of items ordered
        System.out.println("Price of items ordered: $" + dFinalPrice);

        //Sales tax associated with the purchase
        System.out.println("Sales tax: $" + SALES_TAX * dFinalPrice );

        //Total amount due by the customer to Grapefruit Co. 
        System.out.println("Total amount due: $" + (SALES_TAX * dFinalPrice + dFinalPrice ));
```

Comment: I've replaced the suggested section with your code `for(int i = 0; i < naNumber.length; i++){
 int itemTotal = itemPrices[i] * naNumber[i];
 nTotal += itemTotal;
}` but it is giving me an array out of bounds error now when I run the program? Also, if I do not pass the nTotal variable the `calculateTotalPrice`method is unusable?

Comment: I have changed my answer, take a look now. Your array is size 100, which would give the outofboundsexception in your price array.

Comment: That seemed to work better, now I'm curious to the fact why it does not compile properly? If you look at my response to your comment above on the initial question I am entering `1, 2, 6, 10`and the code outputs `0, $0.0, $0.0, $0.0`respectively

Comment: Does it work as it should now? You were not using a loop to calculate the total sum of the items.

Comment: It compiles fine, without any errors, but the results are still `0, $0.0, $0.0, $0.0`respectively in the output. It should be `Total items ordered: 3` `Price of items ordered: $747.00` `Sales Tax: $48.55` `Total amount due: $795.55`

Comment: The output is now working but not right. If I enter `1, 10`the output is the following: `Total items ordered: 1
Price of items ordered: $3039.0
Sales tax: $197.535
Total amount due: $3236.535` So, it is taking the number ordered properly, but the price of the item ordered is wrong? Is there an issue with my array?

Comment: Change `naNumber[nCount] = input.nextInt();` to `naNumber[nCount -1] = input.nextInt();`. You're putting it in the wrong index.

Comment: That gives me an array.outofbounds error. I think the issue is with the for statement in the `calculateFinalPrice`method. `double itemTotal = itemPrices[i] * naNumber[i];`, if I change the * to + the value changes but it is still not right?

Comment: Look at what array the exception is pointing to and what values are in play.

Comment: I do not follow.. The values are `{49,299,329,399,199,1299,1199,999,599}`but if I enter `1`followed by `10`to end the program and compile it gives amount $3,039.00? I don't understand why this issue is occuring...